# Which singular perturbation method should be used for this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

Consider the system

$$ \varepsilon \dfrac{dx}{dt} = -(x^3 - ax + b)$$

$$ \dfrac{db}{dt} = x - x_a$$

where $\varepsilon \ll 1$.  Applying regular perturbation methods isn't suitable because when $\varepsilon = 0$, the system turns into a differential - algebraic system.

Which singular perturbation method is best for problems similar to this?

Comment: What kind of initial conditions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use geometric singular perturbation theory, see

C. Kuehn, *Multiple Time Scale Dynamics*, Springer, 2015.

In this case, the so-called reduced slow system yields the (invariant) critical manifold
\begin{equation}
 C_0 = \left\{ (x,b) \vert b = x(a-x^2) \right\},
\end{equation}
with the slow flow on that manifold determined by $\frac{\text{d} b}{\text{d} t} = x-x_a$.

The reduced fast system, in the fast time variable $\tau = \frac{t}{\epsilon}$, we see that $b$ is (to leading order) constant in this time variable, while $x$ obeys
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} \tau} = a x - x^3 - b.
\end{equation}

**Addition:** For this particular model, it is very instructive to look into (singular perturbation) analysis on the [Fitzhugh Nagumo model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitzHugh%E2%80%93Nagumo_model), or the [van der Pol equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pol_oscillator). Kuehn's book is a good starting point for that, too.